# Data aggregation based on time in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create aggregated data based on a time dimension as follows:
Example of data: 
DateTime,FlowID,Volume 
t0,1,100 
t1,2,200 
t2,3,300 
t2,4,400 
t2,5,100 
t3,4,100

When I visualize sum(Volume) over the DateTime dimension, Tableau correctly shows the total volume for time t2 as the sum of all the records at time t2 (300+400+100). 
I am also trying to get a view that shows a table based on hours of the day as follows: 
                                      DateTime 
                           0      1      2      ...      23 
----------------------------------------------------- 
Sum Volume      x      y      z      ...       t 
Max Volume       a      b      c      ...      d

I want Max Volume to be the sort of "local maximum " during the hour (in this case the sum of all volume records across all the FlowID instances that occurred within the same DateTime t2). 
 
I have looked into the running_max function as follows: 
running_max(sum([Volume]),-2,0), but that only gives me the last two records at time t2.
I don't know a-priori how many records end up being at exactly the same time, so I can't use -2 or -3 deterministically. 
 
Any ideas?

Comment: You state you want Max Volume to be "in this case the SUM of" ... Do you mean "the MAX of" ...? If so, then wouldn't just Max(Volume) be enough, i.e. changing the aggregation function to Max?

Comment: I want the max volume row to be the max of the sum of all the volume values that exist at the same DateTime value. In this case, if times t1 and t2 are within the same hour mark (hour 1 under the DateTime table), the sum of all FlowID for t1 is 200 (only one record), the sum of all FlowID for t2 is 800 (300+400+100), so the max volume that should appear in the table for column 1 should be 800 (max of volume sum at times t1 and t2, which is max(200,800))

Answer (score 0):

Try window_max(sum(Volume)) which is a table calc. So you'll need to also specify which dimension to use for addressing, i.e., compute using. That is as important as the formula and might take a little experimentation to get right.

Based on your description, I think you want to compute using FlowId.

Comment: I have tried that. The problem with window_max is that you have to set the size of the window. Instead, I want to use the DateTime field instead. That is, I want the aggregation to occur when the DateTime field is the same (better yet, if the values in the DateTime field are within a range of each other, say 5 seconds)

Comment: You don't have to set the size of the window. The second two arguments to window_max() are optional. If you leave off the last two arguments, then Tableau will return the max over the entire window which is defined by the dimensions used for partitioning. That is, look at all the dimensions in your visualization, select one (or more) for addressing aka the compute using dimensions. All other dimensions determine the partitioning into windows.

Comment: You don't have to set the size of the window. The second two arguments to window_max() are optional. If you leave off the last two arguments, then Tableau will return the max over the entire window which is defined by the dimensions used for partitioning. Look at all the dimensions in your visualization, select one (or more) for addressing aka the compute using dimensions. All other dimensions determine partitioning.  So compute using FlowId and set the DateTime field in your vizas a dimension instead of a measure, using a calculated field if you want to bin time into non standard chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a proper [DateTime] aggregation as described [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dates_levels.html) - from menu shown on that page you need "Hour" in blue rectangle.

Then put MAX([Volume]) on rows and you should be fine.